# jquery tip on appearance of a button

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div say div1 and I want when that div1 is completely scrolled then a button to appear on the navigation bar...else the button should remain hidden. I have tried the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#b1").hide();
    var h=$("#d1").height();
    var h1=$("#d2").height();
    var eventPosition=h+h1;
    $(window).scroll(function{
        if(window.screenY>=eventPosition)
        {
            fireEvent();
        }
        else{
            fireEvent1();
        }
    });
fireEvent()
{
    $("#b1").show();

}
fireEvent1()
{
    $("#b1").hide();
}
    });
```

Comment: you need `function` in front of `fireEvent1` and `fireEvent`

Answer (score 0):

you missed the function word

```
$(function () {
    $("#b1").hide();
    var h = $("#d1").height();
    var h1 = $("#d2").height();
    var eventPosition = h + h1;
    $(window).scroll(function{
        if (window.screenY >= eventPosition) {
            fireEvent();
        }
        else {
            fireEvent1();
        }
    });
    function fireEvent()
    {
        $("#b1").show();

    }
    function fireEvent1()
    {
        $("#b1").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").hide(); 

     $(window).scroll(function(){

        if(($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()) >=
        $(document).height())
        {
            fireEvent();
        }
        else{
            fireEvent1();
        }
    });

function fireEvent()
{
    $("#b1").show();

}
function fireEvent1()
{
    $("#b1").hide();

}
    });
```

Here is your code with some changes. When it gets to the bottom a button will be shown. 
Here is a jsfiddle example.
https://jsfiddle.net/okisinch/6t02bum1/1/

I hope this will help you to find the solution to your problem.